# how to add checkbox with RadAutocomplete list Items?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

i want to have Telerik Autocomplete suggestion box(textbox) With multiselect  dropdownlist in Winforms ...Any one Give  Example?

```
Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()       
        Me.SetupAutoComplete(Me.RadAutoCompleteBox2)
        Me.radDropDownListAutoCompleteMode.DropDownStyle = RadDropDownStyle.DropDownList
        Me.radDropDownListAutoCompleteMode.SelectedIndex = 0
        AddHandler Me.radDropDownListAutoCompleteMode.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf OnRadDropDownListAutoCompleteModeSelectedIndexChanged
End Sub




    Private Sub SetupAutoComplete(ByVal radAutoCompleteBox As RadAutoCompleteBox)
        AddHandler radAutoCompleteBox.Items.CollectionChanged, AddressOf OnItemsCollectionChanged
        radAutoCompleteBox.AutoCompleteDisplayMember = "Name"
        radAutoCompleteBox.AutoCompleteValueMember = "Email"
        AddHandler radAutoCompleteBox.ListElement.VisualItemFormatting, AddressOf OnListElementVisualItemFormatting
        radAutoCompleteBox.AutoCompleteDataSource = New BindingSource(Me.GetAutoCompleteDataSource(), String.Empty)
        radAutoCompleteBox.DropDownMaxSize = New Size(200, 0)
        'Me.FillList(radAutoCompleteBox.Items)
    End Sub
```

the above code is added to create and populate data in Autocomplete suggestion box list.. How to add checkbox with list item of Suggestion box returned Result?

Comment: This forum is to help you work on the issue you are facing. Let us know what you have tried first.